# How to Remove Extended File Path VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[vs_code_extended_filepath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlHNz.png)

I want to remove the extended file path in VS Code, but do not know where to update the correct settings. I have seen many tutorials with only the yellow file path indicating the current directory, but then below there are tons of other, unnecessary file paths that I would like to hide if possible. Not sure why they show up.

Comment: Short answer No, or you have to code a task that calls the program you want and then attach to that debugger

Comment: you can also map a drive to your long path then it is a lot less text, create a Python virtual environment in your workspace, choose shorter directory names